# Looking for formula that will make some characters lower case and some characters upper case in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make TAMPA, FL into Tampa, FL, but I don't know the correct formula to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Title Case in excel uses the function `PROPER()` I think you'll have to add a couple of other formulas to get exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365, try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,PROPER(TEXTBEFORE(A1,",")),UPPER(TEXTAFTER(A1,",")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment, though not an exact answer -- it would be if someone converted the VBA metacode as in this [StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224731/parse-city-state-and-zip-from-text-formatted-as-city-state-zip) to something useful:

1. Use INSTR(RIGHT(line, 4), ", "), **verify** that the text in the line ends in comma + space + exactly two-character state (and province? territory?) postal abbreviation. (This presumes that two characters are **always** used, which is not true for [Mexican states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Mexico_State-Abbreviation_Codes) and other countries.) As part of verification, you might check that the two-character postal abbreviation is in a list.
2. Split the cell with *City, ST* into two cells, possibly omitting the comma + space entirely (to be added back in later).
3. Use PROPER() to fix City case (which will also correct multi-word cities, e.g., *New York City*.
4. Use UPPER() to fix state abbreviations.
5. This is a useful way to store the data, and may make postal code lookup[ easier.